# Multiprocessing nested for loop with counter

Tags: python, multithreading, list, multiprocessing, pool

I am looking for simple solution which can help me use full power of my PC to process my data. I think, dividing task onto different core would help in reducing in processing time, but I donot know how to do it, I have searched on stackoverflow for the similar problem but not any solution could resolve my problem. I am processing data of around length: 3000 and since I am using nested for loop to find the number of similar(in +- 0.5 range) elements in the list, it will run 3000x3000 times which takes around 2 minutes and I want to reduce the time taken.

```
repeat= []
values = []
for i in completeList:
    count = 0
    for j in completeList:
        if isfloat(i) and isfloat(j):
            if float(i)-0.5 <= float(j) <= float(i)+0.5:
                count = count + 1
    repeat.append(count)
    values.append(i)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

with regards,
Manish

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because the definitions of `isfloat` and `completeList` are absent. But if these were as trivial as one might think, I am surprised that it takes 2 minutes to run this. Also, in your double loop, if the list has 3000 elements, 3000 times you will be comparing two elements with the same identity. Do you really want to be doing that? You should publish `isfloat` and `completeList` if it something other than a simple `list` instance.

Comment: On my desktop where `completeList` was 3000 numbers and `isfloat` just returned `True`, the program ran in under 4 seconds. With such trivial processing, nothing significant could be gained by using multiprocessing due to the overhead of creating processes and transferring data to and from one address space to another. This is why we need to see *more* of your code. Also, compute `float(i)` just once.

Comment: completeList is just a normal list with length of  around 3000-4000. and yes, isfloat just returns true and false. My main goal is to found out all the elements within a specific range (float(i)-0.5 <= float(j) <= float(i)+0.5) and count them.

Comment: Most likely an *algorithmic* approach is much faster than parallelisation. For the most part, most operations are done at O(n^2) that could be done at O(n) (provided the data is not highly degenerate) – which is much, much better speedup than parallelism can even theoretically provide. For starters, filtering the ``completeList`` via ``isfloat`` and converting every element to ``float`` *before the nested loop* is basically a free O(n^2)-to-O(n) optimisation. The element-wise comparison could be sped up by sorting and moving window. But as said, this needs a [mcve] to be certain it's worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you still did not post the actual code for `isfloat` or show what the elements of `completeList` look like, the best I can do is conjecture on what they might be. It makes a difference because as I mentioned, the more CPU required to execute `isfloat` and `float` to convert the elements of `completeList`, the greater the gains to be had by using multiprocessing.

For **CASE 1** I am assuming that `completeList` is composed of strings and that `isfloat` needs to use a regular expression to determine whether the string matches our expected floating point format and that `float` therefore needs to convert from a string. This would be what I would imagine to be the most CPU-intensive case. For **CASE 2** `completeList` is composed of floats, `isfloat` just returns `True` and `float` does not have to do any real conversion.

My desktop has 8 core processors:

**CASE 1**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
import re
from functools import partial

def isfloat(s):
    return not re.fullmatch(r'\d*\.\d+', s) is None

def single_process(complete_list):
    #repeat = []
    values = []
    for idx_i, v_i in enumerate(complete_list):
        count = 0
        for idx_j, v_j in enumerate(complete_list):
            if idx_i == idx_j:
                continue # don't compare an element with itself
            if isfloat(v_i) and isfloat(v_j):
                f_i = float(v_i)
                if f_i-0.5 <= float(v_j) <= f_i+0.5:
                    count = count + 1
        # repeat will end up being a copy of complete_list
        # why are we doing this?
        #repeat.append(v_i)
        values.append(count) # these are actually counts
    return values


def multi_worker(complete_list, index_range):
    values = []
    for idx_i in index_range:
        v_i = complete_list[idx_i]
        count = 0
        for idx_j, v_j in enumerate(complete_list):
            if idx_i == idx_j:
                continue # don't compare an element with itself
            if isfloat(v_i) and isfloat(v_j):
                f_i = float(v_i)
                if f_i-0.5 <= float(v_j) <= f_i+0.5:
                    count = count + 1
        values.append(count) # these are actually counts
    return values


def multi_process(complete_list):

    def split(a, n):
        k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
        return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))

    n = len(complete_list)
    POOL_SIZE = mp.cpu_count()
    range_splits = split(range(0, n), POOL_SIZE)
    pool = mp.Pool(POOL_SIZE)
    value_lists = pool.map(partial(multi_worker, complete_list), range_splits)
    values = []
    # join results together:
    for value_list in value_lists:
        values.extend(value_list)
    return values

def main():
    # generate 3000 random numbers:
    random.seed(0)
    complete_list = [str(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0)) for _ in range(3000)]
    t = time.time()
    values = single_process(complete_list)
    print(time.time() - t, values[0:10], values[-10:-1])

    t = time.time()
    values = multi_process(complete_list)
    print(time.time() - t, values[0:10], values[-10:-1])


# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
27.7540442943573 [1236, 1491, 1464, 1477, 1494, 1472, 1410, 1450, 1502, 1537] [1485, 1513, 1513, 1501, 1283, 1538, 804, 1459, 1457]
7.187546253204346 [1236, 1491, 1464, 1477, 1494, 1472, 1410, 1450, 1502, 1537] [1485, 1513, 1513, 1501, 1283, 1538, 804, 1459, 1457]
```

**CASE 2**

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import random
from functools import partial

def isfloat(s):
    return True

def single_process(complete_list):
    values = []
    for idx_i, v_i in enumerate(complete_list):
        count = 0
        for idx_j, v_j in enumerate(complete_list):
            if idx_i == idx_j:
                continue # don't compare an element with itself
            if isfloat(v_i) and isfloat(v_j):
                f_i = float(v_i)
                if f_i-0.5 <= float(v_j) <= f_i+0.5:
                    count = count + 1
        values.append(count) # these are actually counts
    return values


def multi_worker(complete_list, index_range):
    values = []
    for idx_i in index_range:
        v_i = complete_list[idx_i]
        count = 0
        for idx_j, v_j in enumerate(complete_list):
            if idx_i == idx_j:
                continue # don't compare an element with itself
            if isfloat(v_i) and isfloat(v_j):
                f_i = float(v_i)
                if f_i-0.5 <= float(v_j) <= f_i+0.5:
                    count = count + 1
        values.append(count) # these are actually counts
    return values


def multi_process(complete_list):

    def split(a, n):
        k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
        return (a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))

    n = len(complete_list)
    POOL_SIZE = mp.cpu_count()
    range_splits = split(range(0, n), POOL_SIZE)
    pool = mp.Pool(POOL_SIZE)
    value_lists = pool.map(partial(multi_worker, complete_list), range_splits)
    values = []
    # join results together:
    for value_list in value_lists:
        values.extend(value_list)
    return values

def main():
    # generate 3000 random numbers:
    random.seed(0)
    complete_list = [random.uniform(1.0, 3.0) for _ in range(3000)]
    t = time.time()
    values = single_process(complete_list)
    print(time.time() - t, values[0:10], values[-10:-1])

    t = time.time()
    values = multi_process(complete_list)
    print(time.time() - t, values[0:10], values[-10:-1])


# required for Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
4.181002378463745 [1236, 1491, 1464, 1477, 1494, 1472, 1410, 1450, 1502, 1537] [1485, 1513, 1513, 1501, 1283, 1538, 804, 1459, 1457]
1.325998067855835 [1236, 1491, 1464, 1477, 1494, 1472, 1410, 1450, 1502, 1537] [1485, 1513, 1513, 1501, 1283, 1538, 804, 1459, 1457]
```

**Results**

For CASE 1 the speedup was 3.86, for CASE 2 the speedup was only 3.14.